# C++ abstraction of libpng causes Crash in malloc -- While deleting a "Jagged" 2D Array

Tags: c++, sigabrt, libpng

The class corresponding to this crash is:

```
#ifndef IMAGE_DATA_
#define IMAGE_DATA_

 #include <stdexcept>

template <typename data_type>
class ImageData 
{
public:
  ImageData(unsigned long width, unsigned long height);
  ~ImageData();
  data_type **&get_data();
  unsigned long int get_width() const
  {
    return _m_Width;
  }
  unsigned long int get_height() const
  {
    return _m_Height;
  }
protected:
  ImageData(ImageData &copy);
  ImageData& operator= (ImageData &copy);
private:
  data_type **_m_rData;
  unsigned long _m_Width;
  unsigned long _m_Height;
};

template <typename data_type>
ImageData<data_type>::ImageData(unsigned long width, unsigned long height) :
  _m_rData(NULL),
  _m_Width(width),
  _m_Height(height)
{
  if (width == 0 || height == 0)
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid width or height");

  try {
    _m_rData = new data_type*[_m_Height]();
    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < _m_Height; ++i) {
      _m_rData[i] = NULL;
    }
    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < _m_Height; ++i) {
      _m_rData[i] = new data_type[_m_Width];
    }
  }
  catch (std::bad_alloc e) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failure to create space for Image");
  }
}

template <typename data_type>
ImageData<data_type>::~ImageData()
{
  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < _m_Height; ++i) {
      delete [] _m_rData[i];
     _m_rData[i] = NULL;
  }
  delete [] _m_rData;
  _m_rData = NULL;
}

template <typename data_type>
data_type **&ImageData<data_type>::get_data()
{
  return _m_rData;
}

#endif
```

And it is used in the following manner:

```
PNGFileReader::PNGFileReader(const std::string &path) :
  _m_Image(NULL),
  _m_pPNG(NULL),
  _m_pPNGInfo(NULL)
{
   ...
  /*
   * Read Image in all at once into users data
   */  
  _m_Image = new ImageData<unsigned char>(width, height);
  png_read_image(_m_pPNG, _m_Image->get_data());
  png_read_end(_m_pPNG, NULL);
  fclose(_m_CFilePointer);
  _m_CFilePointer = NULL;
}

PNGFileReader::~PNGFileReader()
{
  if (_m_CFilePointer) {
    fclose(_m_CFilePointer);
  }
  png_destroy_read_struct(&_m_pPNG, &_m_pPNGInfo, NULL);
  delete _m_Image;
}
```

When stepping through with the debugger the _m_rData in the ImageData class is the same pointer as when I used new on it. I have even tried to wrap the delete statement inside ImageData destructor with if == NULL statments. However, I still get a sigabrt while running my code. The stack trace from gdb is:

```
0   __GI_raise  raise.c 64  0x3512a36285    
1   __GI_abort  abort.c 91  0x3512a37b9b    
2   __libc_message  libc_fatal.c    198 0x3512a77a7e    
3   malloc_printerr malloc.c    5021    0x3512a7dda6    
4   _int_free   malloc.c    3942    0x3512a7f08e    
5   ImageData<unsigned char>::~ImageData    imagedata.h 57  0x40236d    
6   PNGFileReader::~PNGFileReader   pngfilereader.cpp   59  0x401ed3    
7   main    main.cpp    8   0x40246a
```

---

**UPDATE**

For anyone that is curios the following now works. Apparently it is an issue with how png_alligns its data. This forces you I guess to use libpng's method calls which internally use free and malloc, not new. This is essentially the same things as calling free(data) where data was created with data = new type[N]. The code below depicts how to correctly use libpng.

```
#ifndef PNG_FILE_READER_H_
#define PNG_FILE_READER_H_

#include "imagedata.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <png.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <typename data_type>
class ImageData;

class PNGFileReader
{
  public:
    // Ctor and Dtor
    PNGFileReader(const std::string &path);
    ~PNGFileReader();

    // For testing purposes
    friend std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &out, 
      PNGFileReader *object)
    {
      for (unsigned long i = 0; i < object->get_image_height(); ++i) {
        for (unsigned long j = 0; j < object->get_image_width(); ++j) {
          png_byte c = object->_m_ImageData[i][j];
          out << c;
        }   
      }
      return out;
    }

    // Getters
    long unsigned int get_image_width() const;
    long unsigned int get_image_height() const;

  private:
    // Helper functions:
    bool _create_png_structs();

    // Member variables:
    FILE *_m_CFilePointer;
    unsigned long int _m_ImageWidth;
    unsigned long int _m_ImageHeight;
    png_bytepp _m_ImageData;
    png_structp _m_pPNG;
    png_infop _m_pPNGInfo;

    // Enums
    enum PNGBOOL {NOT_PNG, PNG};
    enum PNGERRORS {ERROR, SUCCESS};
};

#endif /* PNG_FILE_READER_H_ */

#include "pngfilereader.h"
#include "filereader.h"
#include <stdexcept>


PNGFileReader::PNGFileReader(const std::string &path) :
  _m_ImageData(NULL),
  _m_pPNG(NULL),
  _m_pPNGInfo(NULL)
{
  /*
   * Check if first 8 bytes are the correct PNG header
   */ 
  enum {BYTES_TO_READ = 8};
  unsigned char sig[BYTES_TO_READ];
  FileReader(path, sig, BYTES_TO_READ);
  bool not_png = png_sig_cmp(sig, 0, BYTES_TO_READ);
  if (not_png) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Your file is not of PNG format");
  }

  /*
   * Create the png structs using a FILE *. libpng requires
   * this type and will not take a C++ stream
   */ 
  _m_CFilePointer = fopen(path.c_str(), "rb");
  if (!_m_CFilePointer) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failure to open PNG file");
  }
  if (!_create_png_structs()) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failure to create PNG structs");   
  }

  /*
   * Initialize PNG io and read data into PNG structs
   */ 
  png_init_io(_m_pPNG, _m_CFilePointer);
  png_read_info(_m_pPNG, _m_pPNGInfo);
  _m_ImageHeight = png_get_image_height(_m_pPNG, _m_pPNGInfo);
  _m_ImageWidth = png_get_rowbytes(_m_pPNG, _m_pPNGInfo);

  /*
   * Create sufficient PNG Space and Read Image in all at
   * once into users data. Note that you have to use png's
   * types to prevent sigabrt (6) while freeing memory.
   */
  _m_ImageData = (png_bytepp)png_malloc(_m_pPNG,
    sizeof(png_bytep)*_m_ImageHeight);
  if (_m_ImageData == NULL) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Memory allocation failure");
  }
  for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < _m_ImageHeight; ++i) {
     _m_ImageData[i] = NULL;
  }
  for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < _m_ImageHeight; ++i) {
    _m_ImageData[i] = (png_bytep)png_malloc(_m_pPNG,
      sizeof(png_byte)*_m_ImageWidth);
    if (_m_ImageData[i] == NULL) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Memory allocation failure.");
    }
  }
  png_read_image(_m_pPNG, _m_ImageData);
  png_read_end(_m_pPNG, NULL);
  fclose(_m_CFilePointer);
  _m_CFilePointer = NULL;
}

PNGFileReader::~PNGFileReader()
{
  if (_m_CFilePointer) {
    fclose(_m_CFilePointer);
  }
  /*
   * Free all resources (-1)
   */
  png_free_data(_m_pPNG, _m_pPNGInfo, PNG_FREE_ALL, -1);
  for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < _m_ImageHeight; ++i) {
    png_free(_m_pPNG, _m_ImageData[i]);
  }
  free(_m_ImageData);
  png_destroy_read_struct(&_m_pPNG, &_m_pPNGInfo, NULL);
}
// Getters
long unsigned int PNGFileReader::get_image_width() const
{
  return _m_ImageWidth;
}

long unsigned int PNGFileReader::get_image_height() const
{
  return _m_ImageHeight;
}

// Private helper functions
bool PNGFileReader::_create_png_structs()
{
  /* 
   * Create the pointer to main libpng struct, as well as
   * two info structs to maintain information after, and
   * prior to all operations on png m_Data. Only necessary
   * to release resource after function succeeds.
   */
  _m_pPNG = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, (png_voidp)NULL,
    NULL, NULL);
  if (!_m_pPNG){
    return PNGFileReader::ERROR;
  }

  _m_pPNGInfo = png_create_info_struct(_m_pPNG);
  if (!_m_pPNGInfo) {
    return PNGFileReader::ERROR;
  }

  return PNGFileReader::SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: BTW--The structure you have here with the `**` is not exactly the same as a `[][]` 2D array and is sometimes called a "ragged-" or "jagged-" array. Yes, it can be dereferenced with the same syntax, but it is laid out differently in memory. This way has the advantage of being easy to dynamically size, which the other does not.

Comment: I think the problem is comming in while using libpng, I have removed the libpng calls and this is where the issue is comming in.

Comment: If `libpng` thinks that you're passing a real 2D array and you are instead passing a jagged array then that would, indeed, cause trouble. In principle the trouble could manifest in any way, but overwriting the `malloc` bookkeepping data and therefore causing `free` to crash is very plausible.

Comment: If your environment supports some kind of allocation bounds checking, try turning that on. Alternately run in `valgrind` or some other allocation verifier (and be ready to wait...valgrind is *slow*).

Comment: If I do the memory allocation local to PNGFileReader I do not get the crash using a "jagged" array. It only crashes when placing the jagged array in another class. The difference being that locally I can use png's type png_bytepp, png_bytep, and png_byte. Where as using my template class I am forced to use a base type and then use ** to signify a jagged array. I guess I will have to encapsulte the memory management inside of PNGFileReader <sigh>. I would still like to know what is happening internally so I am not just changing things as a work around.

Comment: Hmmm...I wrote my answer from a slightly different perspective, but it should point you in the direction of a solution. You can still allocate an array of index pointer that point into a contiguous block of memory. It cost s you some extra space, of course, but...

Comment: @Ben Reading through the libpng documentation they use jagged arrays. Many time before hand it is not know what the size of the image is, how else are you supposed to create the right size of memory, if you don't know what the size of the image is before hand?

Comment: @MatthewHoggan, I stand corrected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a really 2D array to pass to a library, but want to have the flexibility of a jagged array, what you do is

1. Allocate the first level pointer block as usual
2. Instead of allocating `m` separate rows of `n` cells (one for each pointer in the first level block) you allocate a single set of `n*m` cells and then set the first level pointers to point at every `n`th location. This way the main allocation is sized and laid out in memory just as a 2D array, but you can still use the two-pointer-dereference `[][]` syntax to get to the cells.
3. Pass the start of the second level allocation to the library.

This works because there are strict requirements on who multidimensional arrays are laid out in memory (i.e. the must be contiguous at every level of interpretation).

Comment: the second argument to png_read_image() is a png_bytepp, which is defined as a unsigned char long* long*. I don't know if this is possible.